# Is this function continuous? Polar coordinates "identity"

Tags: calculus, general-topology, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Is the function $f:\mathbb D\to S^1\times I$ given in polar coordinates by $f(r,θ)=(θ,r)$ (or to be precise: $f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)=((\cos\theta,\sin\theta),r)$) continuous?

How would one prove it?

My guess would be yes, since geometricly it is almost the identity, if looking on it with the right prespective. how would I prove it tho?

Thanks

P.S:
This is standard notation in topology, but let me make it clear: $\mathbb D$ is the closed unit disk in $\mathbb R^2$, $S^1$ is it's boundary (the $\mathbb R^2$ sphere), and $I$ is the unit interval

P.S2:

Lemme explain my situation, and I hope you could help me use what I want properly. Let G:S1×I→X be homotopy between the constant y to a function g:S1→X i.e G is continuous with G(x,0)=y,G(x,1)=g(x). I want to define f:D→X by f(r,θ)=G(θ,r) and to claim f to be continuous. our discussion here should make f continuous in D{0,0} as a composition of continuous , and I hope that the fact that for r=0 it doesn't matter for G what θ is (it will always be y) will fix the continuity in (0,0). How could I show that?

Comment: What is $\mathbb{D}$? What is $I$?

Comment: @JuliánAguirre : $\mathbb{D}$ is probably the disk of radius $R$ and $I = [0,R]$

Comment: @JuliánAguirre: I thought this was standard notation, but I edited the original question to clarify. thanks!

Comment: If you'll forgive my putting words in your mouth, after your latest edit you're "really" putting an equivalence relation $\sim$ on the cylinder by collapsing $S^{1} \times \{0\}$ to a point, and asking whether the quotient space $(S^{1} \times I)/{}\sim$ is homeomorphic to the disk via the map $f$. The answer is "yes"; I'll trust @JuliánAguirre to update his answer. :)

Comment: I answered the OP's question, not your interpretation of the question.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre: Yes, I understand that. :) I just didn't want to swoop in an answer what the question appears to have morphed into without giving you the chance to update if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ is not defined at $(0,0)$. However it is continuous from $\mathbb{D}\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ to $S^1\times(0,1]$.

Let $X$ be a topological space (that for simplicity I will asume is a metric space with metric $d$) and $G\colon S^1\times[\,0,1\,]\to X$ continuous and such that $G(\theta,0)=y\in X$ for all $\theta\in S^1$. Define $f\colon\mathbb{D}\to X$ by
$$
f(r,\theta)=\begin{cases} G(r,\theta) & r\ne0,\\
y & r=0.\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is continuous. Continuity in $\mathbb{D}\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ is clear.

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Since $S^1\times[\,0,1\,]$ is compact, $G$ is uniformly continuous. There exists $r_\epsilon>0$ such that if $0\le r\le\epsilon$ then $d(G(r,\theta),y)\le\epsilon$ for all $\theta\in S^1$. Then also $d(f(r,\theta),y)\le\epsilon$.

Comment: I see, thanks! Lemme explain my situation, and I hope you could help me use what I want properly. Let $G:S^1\times I\to X$ be homotopy between the constant $y$ to a function $g:S^1\to X$ i.e $G$ is continuous with $G(x,0)=y,G(x,1)=g(x)$. I want to define $f:\mathbb D\to X$ by $f(r,\theta)=G(\theta,r)$ and to claim $f$ to be continuous. our discussion here should make $f$ continuous in $D\{0,0}$ as a composition of continuous , and I hope that the fact that for $r=0$ it doesn't matter for $G$ what $\theta$ is (it will always be $y$) will fix the continuity in $(0,0)$. How could I show that?

Comment: If $y$ is constant, then you can define $f(0,0)=y$ and this will give you a continuous function.

Comment: I understand that, but my question is how to prove that it would be continuous at 0

Comment: I hace included a proof of continuity of $f$.